# How can I remove ... from a string in PHP?

Tags: php

Hello if I have the following string

**This seems to find the node... ok but the output is below**

How can i remove ... and have it printed? I am using PHP

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use [str_replace](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php):

```
$newString = str_replace('...', '', $string);
```

Using regexes for such simple tasks is just overkill and [will hurt performance](http://atomized.org/2005/04/php-performance-best-practices/):

> Avoid regexes in favor of str_replace() and strstr(). Don’t use regexes unless you really need them. The string functions are much faster.

Comment: hank you! Is there any way to search for 2, 3 or 4 dots ?

Comment: @JBCurious: You could use the consecutive str_replace calls, which imo will still be faster than using regexes (maybe not as elegant, though). Note that when doing so, you need to first replace '....' , then '...' and then '..'!

Answer (score 2):

Also, for simple $strings, you can use

```
$new_string = str_replace('find','replace_with',$old_string);
```

To remove '...' using str_replace, simply:

```
$new_string = str_replace('...','',$old_string);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$new_str = preg_replace('/\.{3,}/', '' , $str);
```

`$str` is the original string

Comment: Thank you! Is there any way to search for 2, 3 or 4 dots ?

Comment: ya that `{3,}` means 3 or more dots, so `{2,}` means 2 or more. `{3,6}` means 3, 4, 5 , or 6. you get the idea!